# Windows 8 Store App - Launch document placed at webserver without downloading locally

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps

I am currently building a Windows 8 Store app and am opening a document in Word client using the following method call.

`await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(Storagefile);`

The problem is that the Storagefile is currently being opened from a local path i.e

`D://document.docx`

I want to be able to open this directly from a webpath i.e.

`https://somepage/document.docx`

but the need is that I cannot download it locally but just Launch it directly from the webpage.

Can this be done?

Comment: Is the requirement that YOU do not write code to fetch the file locally? Or is the requirement that there be no such local file downloaded at any stage (other than, maybe, Word itself which of course you cannot control)?

Comment: The requirement is that there be no such local file downloaded at any stage.

Comment: You could try LaunchUriAsync, but note that even when you just use Word and open a URI like that, the file is being downloaded to the local machine

Comment: LaunchUriAsync method launches an IE Browser and gives the Open Word message:

** "Do you want to Open abc.docx from http://mysite.com?
  |Open|    |Cancel|" **

And then when I click open, the document opens in the word client.

This solution is obviously close to what I want..... But can the above mentioned Open Word message be bypassed somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way to open the documents directly from the server without downloading them locally.

**Url Protocols** can be used to achieve the direct opening functionality.

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri( "ms-word:https://somepage/document.docx"));
```